# Customizing highlighting faces in Emacs: Only change the background color

Tags: emacs, emacs-faces

Is there any way to define a face in Emacs (e.g. highlight such as `hl-line`) so that it only changes the background color (and have Emacs use the foreground color as if the word was not highlighted).

More specifically, I tried the following on the `tango-dark` theme

```
(custom-set-faces
 '(region ((t (:inherit nil :background "RoyalBlue4"))))
 '(highlight ((t (:inherit region :background "dark olive green"))))
 '(hl-line ((t (:inherit highlight)))))
```

and, as can be seen below, region highlighting **does** respect the foreground font (i.e. it only changes the background color):

[image]

**but** the  highlighting of the current line does't:

[image]

Why? and how can I get the same effect with `hl-line`?

### Update:

This seems to a bug in the `tango-dark` theme (a builtin theme of Emacs). The code works well with the default theme (which loads with `emacs -Q`). I posted this on the official bugs mailing list.

Comment: check your parens on the region line; =) after i fixed that things seemed to work as you want;  btw, having a mode helper like paredit will prevent most of these issues!

Comment: More precisely, remove the closing parens after `custom-set-faces` and the `region` line -- after that, the code works fine for me on Emacs 23.1.1

Comment: Thanks @Thomas, I updated the code and the OP, but I still don't get the desired effect. Hmm

Comment: Thanks @assem. I updated the code and the OP but I still don't get the desired effect.

Comment: Could this be a side-effect of your theming? Can you try and see if the same effect happens when you start emacs with `-Q` ?

Comment: @Thomas. You are right. I am not having this problem with the default theme that loads with `emacs -Q`. For reference, I am using `tango-dark` above. The odd thing is that this is one the themes that Emacs now provides.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I struggled with this some time ago, and it seems to be a bug of the color theme.

I've come up with a workaround, however. This works for me:

```
(load-theme 'tango-dark t)
(set-face-attribute 'highlight nil :foreground 'unspecified)
```

Comment: This seems to do the trick. Thanks! I will wait a bit in case anyone has a better answer and will accept it otherwise. This work like a charm.

Comment: Same problem and solution with the `wombat` theme.

Answer (score 0):

I had a bit similar problem:

```
(add-hook 'after-make-frame-functions
  (lambda (frame)
    (select-frame frame)
      (when (display-graphic-p frame)
       (custom-set-faces '(region ((t (:inherit nil :background "RoyalBlue4")))))
     )
```